# Making all images' sources https:// using *.user.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ssl, userjs

EDIT: Why doesn't this work?

```
@match http://tumblr.com/*
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(img).each(function() {
        var i = $(this).attr("src");
        var n = i.replace("http://", "https://");
        $(this).attr("src", function() {
            return n;
        });
    });
});​
```

EDIT: To be clear, I DO NOT OWN THE WEBSITE. I want to have images on sites like https://facebook.com/ and https://tumblr.com/ be on https.

Comment: Is your site itself on https? If so, you could use URL like `'//24.media.thumblr.com/xxx'` and it would work automatically.

Comment: As an alternative, just start your URLs with with `//`, leaving out the protocol.  The browser will use whatever the current protocol is.

Comment: I do not suggest attempting this, it will result in the images being requested twice, once from http and again from https. use `//` as suggested above.

Comment: @KevinB Maybe not all, but definitely some :)

Comment: @KevinB Does this only apply to resources external to your domain or all resources? I've never used it and never noticed when I put my site up with SSL, but I always declare everything with `http://`, so I'm wondering if that's not good practice

Comment: I don't own the website, I mean for viewing images. Hence, user js. I want to edit the tags via user js, not change the website's code to change the tags. It's mostly for the tumblr dashboard.

Comment: @Ian the double request only happens if you change the location of the image after it has began loading or finished loading. Changing from `http://myurl.com/img.jpg` to `https://myurl.com/img.jpg` is like changing from `http://myurl.com/img.jpg` to `http://yoururl.com/img.jpg`, it's an entirely different location so the browser will re-request it.

Comment: @KevinB Ahh right, sorry sorry. That makes sense, that was silly of me. I guess I was asking about normal script/style resources at the head of your page, which I guess is unrelated to the question, but I misunderstood the point of your comment :)

Comment: There is one major flaw in this plan. The root directory for the `htpps` protocol could be something entirely different. I believe the root directory for the `http` protocol is mostly `public_html` and the root directory for the `https` protocol is mostly `private_html`. Unless all sites you're going to try this copied their site to `priate_html` (or whatever their `https` root directory is) this won't work.

Comment: I mostly want this to work on tumblr.com, where they are in the same directory. It should work, but the images aren't changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP was really close, just need to tweak the selector: `$(img)` to `$("img")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").each(function() {
          var link = $(this).attr("src");
          var newLink = link.replace("http://example.com", "//example.com");
          $(this).attr("src", function() {
            return newLink
        });
     });
  });
```

jQuery requires the use of quotes around DOM element selectors, the OP script would throw img not defined.

Comment: Would you mind extending the answer a bit more, for fellow programmers, to understand how it helped to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

hey man it's so simple as far i can understand that you want! You want to change all images src?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("img").each( function() {
var i = $(this).attr("src");
var n = i.replace("http://", "https://");
$(this).attr("src", function() {
return n;
});
});
});
```

Comment: hey man it will change only src but it depends on the domain of tumblr whether it supports https:// secure or not! my hands off from this answer now!

Comment: @WilsonBiggs This should work, but note that this will require every image to be requested twice, as noted in your question's comments. But it might be the best type of solution for your situation where you cannot modify the HTML

Comment: yeah @lan I also thought that he have a number of images and instead of wasting his time on changing his HTML images sources one by one manually he wants to change sources of images quickly with the use of little code. But later i noted that the sources he gave were of that domain which do not supports secure connection(https://). So, the sources will not work!

Comment: I modified it a little so it works as user js, doesn't work... I edited the question with my current script.

Comment: hey man you can't change the domain protocol by only changing the link or source it depends on domain whether it supports this secure connection or protocol feature. TUMBLR.COM does not supports the https:// (secure connection) so, you can't change it by your own.

Comment: Yes it does. https://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9uhi132pd1rdc5dfo1_1280.jpg works fine.

Comment: please explain why you need secure connection?