# Serve Image over https with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, http, ssl, https

I have a Amazon ec2 instance with apache webserver installed. I have used Certbot to install a SSl certificate. I want to display a  Image on my site using javascript. When a user enters in a edit text box I want to dynamically change a image. Im currently using javascript to change it.  When I access the image I get this message "requested an insecure image 'http://myurl.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS. How do I use Https so serve the image?

```
document.getElementById("img").src="http://myurl.jpg"
```

Comment: `How can I fix this?` by using https

Comment: change to 'https://myurl.jpg' ... simple security issue attempting to serve http over https

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804590/making-all-images-sources-https-using-user-js

Answer (score 0):

Replace this: "http://myurl.jpg"
with this: "https://myurl.jpg"

easy enough?

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the protocol in the URL. Then it will default to the same protocol as was used for the page. So if the page was loaded with `https`, it will also use `https` for the image, and there won't be an error:

```
document.getElementById("img").src="//myurl.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want for example image filepaths to load as HTTPS while still using relative paths you must set a `<base href="URL"/>`.

I use file paths like this `<img  src="img/xxx.png" alt="xxx">` but without setting a base URL it will load by default as HTTP. To resolve this add something like this in your head.

`<head>
  <?php
  $BaseDir = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], 0, strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "/") + 1);
echo '<base href="' . $BaseDir . '" />';
  ?>
</head>`